# How to silence automatic gradle build while importing a project to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I import a project to Android Studio, the gradle sync is initiated automatically and I get build failure errors. Because of this I am unable to traverse the code and not able to debug the code. Is there anyway to use Android Studio for just traversing the code flow and not building the code with gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call ./gradlew --stop in a Terminal and it will kill all gradle processes

Comment: Will that also guarantee that I can traverse through the code flow? like finding usages of code (Currently if I select a method and press Ctrl+Shift+G, it says "No usages of this method found", however the method is used in many places..)?

Comment: No! Gradle build is required for that.